# Jekyll blog theme now showing blog posts on GitLab Pages

Tags: ruby, gitlab, jekyll

I've been using the [Emerald jekyll theme](https://github.com/KingFelix/emerald) for my blog on GitHub Pages. It all works great on GitHub, but I've wanted to move to GitLab.

I got the blog working with all necessary gems (like jekyll and jekyll-paginate), but the blog posts aren't working and I get 404.

Test it live [here](https://remieditor.gitlab.io/blog)

I made the [repo](https://gitlab.com/remieditor/blog) public so everyone can have a look and possibly identify my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `.html` extension to your links.

https://remieditor.gitlab.io/blog/plausible-gitlab-moving.html

Github provides an option for serving without the extension, however I don't believe that Gitlab allows this yet. See this thread: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/issues/95

Change your permalink configuration:

```
permalink: /:title:output_ext
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you! Changing the repo to private now

Answer (score 0):

[Since GitLab 11.8 (February 2019)](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/02/22/gitlab-11-8-released/#html-extensions-are-now-automatically-resolved-for-pages-sites) this should work

> ### `.html` extensions are now automatically resolved for Pages sites
>
> A file in your Pages site called `/sub-page.html` can now also be accessed as `/sub-page`, giving you more options over how your site appears to your users.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/) and [`gitlab-org/gitlab-pages` issue 95](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-pages/issues/95)